# Do Pointer Parameters Need To Be Passed By Reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a very simple Linked List. My `addNode(Node* &list, int value)` function only adds a new node to my Linked List if I pass my list by reference. If I pass my list by value it doesn't: `addNode(Node* list, int value)`.

I am aware of what `pass by value` and `pass by reference` are but I thought that a **pointer function parameter** is inherently passing by reference because the pointer points to a memory location (is a reference to the instance). Therefore I thought the `&` is redundant isn't it? Or am I wrong?

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    int   value;

    Node(int nValue=0) : next(NULL), prev(NULL), value(nValue) { }
    ~Node() { cout << "Deleting " << value << endl; }
};

// Why do I need to pass by reference 'list'?
// If I dont then the variable 'linkedList' (in main) doesn't have nodes added to it
void addNode(Node* &list, int value)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(value);
    newNode->prev = list;
    list->next    = newNode;
    list          = newNode;
}

int main()
{
    Node* linkedList = new Node(1);
    addNode(linkedList, 2);

    // TODO: release memory

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse the reference to the **pointer** with what the pointer **points-to**. Its the pointer at the head of the list you need to change as in in/out parameter. What it points-to is only modified to set the back-pointer to the new node.

Comment: If your function modifies the pointer itself rather than just the pointed value, then you need to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "pointer function parameter is inherently passing by reference" is not completely true. You need to take into account that when you pass a pointer to a function, and the pointer points to something, you really pass two things:

- pointer
- pointee

So if the pointer is passed by value, you have:

- pointer passed by value
- pointee passed by reference

In this case you can modify in the function the pointee, yet you cannot modify the pointer.

If the pointer is passed by reference, you have:

- pointer passed by reference
- pointee passed by reference

In this case you can modify both pointer and pointee.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. In your case where you change the pointer inside a function then yes you should pass the pointer by reference. If, on the other hand, you don't change the pointer inside a function then there's no reason to add another level of indirection and pass by reference.

And no, pointers are not automatically passed by reference, they are passed by value just like any other argument. If you don't pass by reference, the pointer will be copied and you only operate on the copy and not the original.

Answer (score 2):

The reference here is necessary because you are attempting to alter the *pointer* as well as the *pointee*.

If you pass the `Node` by pointer, the caller will see any changes to the pointee, but not to the pointer, as a copy of the pointer is made when the function is called. If you pass the `Node` by pointer reference, the caller will see changes to both.

Comment: ah I see so the copy of `linkedList` changes but not `linkedList`.